# Add hours to a datetime field ecto elixir

Tags: elixir, datetime-format, ecto

Here is my model:

```
schema "fixtures" do
    field :sm_id, :integer
    field :local_score, :integer
    field :visitor_score, :integer
    field :local_pen_score, :integer
    field :visitor_pen_score, :integer
    field :ht_score, :string
    field :ft_score, :string
    field :et_score, :string
    field :starting_at, Ecto.DateTime
    belongs_to :local_team, Team, foreign_key: :local_team_id
    belongs_to :visitor_team, Team, foreign_key: :visitor_team_id
    belongs_to :season, Season
    belongs_to :round, Round

    timestamps()
end
```

What I want is to get the live fixtures using the following query:

```
def fixtures_live(query, round_) do
    now = Ecto.DateTime.utc |> Ecto.DateTime.cast!
    query
    |> join(:left, [r], f in assoc(r, :fixtures))
    |> where([r, _], r.id == ^round_.id)
    |> where([_, f], f.starting_at < ^now)
    |> where([_, f], datetime_add(f.starting_at, 2, "hour") > ^now)
    |> select([_, f], f)
end
```

What I do is the following: starting_at < now < starting_at + 2 "hours"

The result is:

```
Ecto.Query.CastError at GET /sports/get_all_fixtures
web/models/round.ex:73: value `#Ecto.DateTime<2017-08-02 16:32:29>` in `where` cannot be cast to type :naive_datetime in query:
```

And if I want to cast as:

```
    |> where([_, f], datetime_add(f.starting_at, 2, "hour") |> Ecto.DateTime.cast! > ^now)
```

The result is:

```
Compiling 11 files (.ex)

== Compilation error in file web/models/round.ex ==
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `Ecto.DateTime.cast!(datetime_add(f.starting_at(), 2, "hour"))` is not a valid query expression
    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.where/3
    (sopitas) web/models/round.ex:73: Sopitas.Round.fixtures_live/2
    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.select/3
    (sopitas) web/models/round.ex:74: Sopitas.Round.fixtures_live/2
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.|>/2
    (sopitas) web/models/round.ex:74: Sopitas.Round.fixtures_live/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `now = NaiveDateTime.utc_now` with your first attempt (the one without the `cast!` in the `where`).

Comment: Excellent!!, It works perfectly!, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

`datetime_add` is [defined](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/555a055634817f8c168b85dbc6d1807a5f9ff6e2/lib/ecto/query/builder.ex#L627) to return a `:naive_datetime`. In order to be able to compare it with a value, `now` should also be a type that can be cast to `:naive_datetime`. `Ecto.DateTime` cannot be cast to `:naive_datetime`, but you can use the new `NaiveDateTime` module in Elixir.

Just change:

```
now = Ecto.DateTime.utc |> Ecto.DateTime.cast!
```

to:

```
now = NaiveDateTime.utc_now
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dogbert's answer, you may want to change your schema to use the `:naive_datetime` or `:utc_datetime` types in the ecto schema, and use the `NaiveDateTime` / `DateTime` modules from the standard library to manipulate the values.

Since Ecto 2.1, the `Ecto.DateTime` types have [been deprecated](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.1.6/CHANGELOG.md#integration-with-elixir-13-calendar-types) and looks like they are [scheduled to be removed in Ecto 2.2](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.1.6/lib/ecto/date_time.ex#L1).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I don't understand your tip. When I was creating my tables I read that it was a recommendation to create datetime fields using :datetime, go to the migration, change :datetime for :utc_datetime and then execute the migration. When I run the migration the model generated using mix ecto.migrate is the one I posted with Ecto.DateTime as a field type.

Comment: `mix ecto.migrate` shouldn't generate any models, it just runs a database migration against your DB.  Models might have been generated by Phoenix with `mix phoenix.gen.html` or similar, but once generated they are usually maintained manually.

Comment: You're right, sorry for my confusion. However, I added a new field using what you suggest :utc_time, but when I add the new field to the model, it gives me the following message:

== Compilation error in file web/models/fixture.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) invalid or unknown type Naive_DateTime for field :feedtime_start

And the same message when I use DateTime, that's why I use Ecto.DateTime